# SQL query goes endless

Tags: sql-server

There are two tables:
SatisDetay

```
Depo    SatisID SatisSira   UrunID    Satici    KdvKod  KDVYuzde    Miktar
AZ01    20001   1           3788898   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20002   1           3788898   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   1           3876390   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   2           3793202   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   3           4046508   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   4           3843387   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   5           3850608   999       AZ       18.00      1
```

And DepoSevkDetay

```
BaslikID    Sira    UrunID   Miktar Fiyat   Depo
20001       1       3792703  1      1       AZ01  
20002       1       4067131  1      1       AZ01  
20003       1       3251881  1      1       AZ01  
20003       2       3251883  1      1       AZ01  
20003       3       3788887  1      1       AZ01  
20003       4       3788890  1      1       AZ01  
20004       1       3761260  2      1       AZ01
```

There is a task to take sum of Miktar by each UrunID and spread it to UrunID in the second table. But the amount of UrunID records may not match. But it is not the only problem. I tried a simple query as below but it executes endlessly

```
 UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.[Miktar] = Table_B.[Miktar]
FROM
    [Retail].[dbo].[tb_DepoSevkDetay] AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT [Miktar], [UrunID] FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
                GROUP BY [UrunID], [Miktar] ) AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.[UrunID] = Table_B.[UrunID]
```

Please help to find out why

Comment: How large are these tables?

Comment: The query looks fine. I tested against sample tables. It helps if you provide DDL / inserts for sample data. One thing - Table_B isn't grouping Miktar by UrunID - change the subquery to: SELECT SUM([Miktar]) as Miktar, [UrunID] FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay] GROUP BY [UrunID]

Comment: Hi, I did as you told, but still query takes indefinite time to execute (1 hour of execution, canceled, checked the tables but no changes made) there were a linked constraint that were preventing to make any changes in SevkDetay table, i modified it, even dropped it, but still query goes on and on. But a simple query to make some changes in tables can be run successfully. The tables hold approximately 1 000 000 rows of data each with 6 columns.